# Randomly dividing a 2d complex enclosed region

Tags: algorithm

First I will define:

- Region: big stuff manually created I want to divide.
- Zone: small stuff I want to generate.

I have a map. The world map in fact. And I want to divide it into small zones. The size of the zones will be dependent on what region the zone is in. For instance very small for Europe (maybe Europe will have like 200 zones) but only a couple of huge ones for the Atlantic Ocean.

I can manually create points to enclose a region. I will create regions for each big space I want it to have different size than other spaces. For instance I will create an enclosed region for Europe. So I got a butch of (latitude, longitude) points defining the limits of the Europe region. The shape is of course not regular and there are holes in the middle of it (I don't want to create small zones over the Mediterranean sea but a big one). So what we got is a huge 2D shape to be filled up with zones.

Zones themselves are n-sized polygons, number of sizes can be randomly chosen or subject to other constraints. The area of each zone is also limited random (like 50 plus/minus 40%) although this constraint again can be relaxed (as exception, not as rule). Zones can not overlap and the whole region must be divided.

The obvious question, any algorithm that look like can be used to solve this problem?
I even have problems to determine if a given point is inside or outside an enclosed region.

Comment: You should define a bit better what kind of zones you would need; for example consider this: 1. cut the region polygon with a vertical line such that you get a polygon of area 50 (you can do this by 'scanning' the region from left to right) 2. repeat. This will produce *n* zones with required properties. But to me it sounds as you would not be happy with such vertical stripes. Therefore please refine the question.

Answer (score 2):

Me, I'd do it the other way round, put a point in the (approximate) centre of all the zones  and compute the [Voronoi Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) of the resulting point set.

**EDIT:** in response to @Unreason's comments.  I don't claim that computing the Voronoi diagram is an answer to the question asked.  I do claim that computing the Voronoi diagram is a suitable method for dividing a planar map into zones which are defined by their closeness to a point.  This may, or may not, satisfy OP's underlying requirement and OP is free to use or ignore my suggestion.

I implied the following, but will now make it explicit: OP, if taken with this suggestion, should define the points (lat,long) at the 'centres' of each zone required and run the algorithm.  Voronoi diagrams are not computed iteratively, if OP doesn't like the solution then OP would have to shift the points around and re-compute.  I guess it would be feasible to write a routine to do this; the hard part, as ever with computational cartography, is in defining a computable rule about how well a trial solution fits (quasi-)aesthetic requirements.

I wouldn't bother, I'd use country capital cities as the points for my zones (relatively densely packed in Europe, relatively sparse in the Atlantic) and let the algorithm run.  Job done.

Perhaps OP might use the locations of all cities with populations over 5 x 10^5 (there are probably about 200 of those in Europe).  Or some other points.

Oh, and computing the Voronoi diagram isn't random either, it's entirely deterministic.  Again, this may or may not satisfy the underlying requirement.

Comment: How would you get initial approximate centres on a complex polygon?

Comment: Also, you don't describe how would you iterate towards a solution if the initial solution is not satisfying the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if a point is inside a polygon follow [point in polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) in wikipedia or use some geometry framework.

The restrictions to divide a polygon into smaller polygons of loosely same size are not very limiting at all, for example if you

- cut the big polygons with vertical and horizontal lines spaced such that on land you will get exactly the targeted are size, then for europe you will satisfy your criteria for most of the zones.
- Inspect them all and for the ones that do not satisfy the criteria you can start modifying the borders with the neighbouring zones in such a way to reach desired size (as you have +/- 40% this should not be hard).
  You can do this by moving the shared nodes or by adding points to the borders and moving only those lines.

Also, before the above, join the zones from the initial cut that are smaller then certain percentage (for example 20% of the target size; these could be islands and other small pieces).

The algorithm would work well for the large number of small zones, but will not work as well for regions that need to be cut into only a few zones (but it would work).